# Implementing Apple Push Notification without an access to a source server

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to implement some push notifications from Twitter in my app. I can connect to  Twitter's stream of user-related events using Sreaming API. Do I need some 'middleman' server between  Twitter API and an iPhone app in order to push a notification to an app ? Maybe I can do it using Parse.com Cloud Code or something similar ?

This question may be helpful not only in the case of the Twitter API but also in case of any server that a developer don't have any access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push a notification you would generally need a server of your own which has been configured to send a notification when some event occurs. If you are using Parse as a backend for your app, you can leverage their backend to allow you to implement [Push Notifications](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) or use a service like [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/)

In the case of the Twitter API, you will need to implement some middleman in either case to get the data from Twitter for your user and parse it to see whether some event has occurred and then send off a notification either using your own custom logic directly to Apple's servers or using Parse or UrbanAirship (or some other service)